# Use php to extract specific information in document

Tags: php, extract

I need to us php to extract the 573 from line N1 and make this a repeatable process.  On the N1 line, there will always be 4 *'s and will always end in ~ and I'll always need the information after the 4th * and before the ~, regardless of length (3 number, 11 numbers, ect.).  FYI- this is for a 204 EDI document.

Example 1: Need a123

`N1*XX*XXXXXXXX*XX*a123~`

Example 2: Need 573

```
PLD*0~
N1*SF*Company A Products*93*573~
N3*2457B Old Address Rd~
N4*DUDE*NC*28333*US~
```

Example 3: Need 350AB45

````
```LAD*PCK*1***L*45289*******0x0x0~
PLD*0~
N1*SF*Company B Products*93*350AB45~
N3*149 ADDRESS DRIVE~
N4*MOUNT SAMSON*PA*16740*US~
````

Is there a good way to extract this info so I can insert it into a MySQL table?  I only need help on the php extraction.  I'll assign it a variable and insert it into the appropriate table.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a regex for this:

```
preg_match('/N1\*[^*]+\*[^*]+\*[^*]+\*(.*)~/', $s, $m);
$result = $m[1];
```

- Match `N1*`
- `[^*]+\*` match not `*` one or more times `+` followed by `*`
- `[^*]+\*` match not `*` one or more times `+` followed by `*`
- `[^*]+\*` match not `*` one or more times `+` followed by `*`
- `(.*)~` match and capture `()` any character multiple times `.*` followed by `~`